# Unit tests @Transactional - Could not commit JPA transaction; transaction marked as rollback only

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I am writing JUnit tests for my Spring app. For one of the scenarios I am getting the exception

`Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly.`

I have read some other questions and answers and they did not help. The scenario I am having problems is pretty simple. I want to check that a unique constraint of an entity field is enforced. I create two entities with the same field and expect a constraint violation exception. The calling method is marked as `@Transactional`, because I want the whole thing to rollback if an exception occurs.

This is the code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = DeadlinesApplication.class)
@Rollback(value = false)
public class UserHelperTest {
    @Autowired
    private UserHelper userHelper;

    @Test(expected = DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
    @Transactional
    public void uniqueUsername() throws NullParameterException {
        User user = userHelper.createUser("uniq1", "password", null, null);
        User user2 = userHelper.createUser("uniq2", "password", null, null);
        User user3 = userHelper.createUser("uniq2", "password", null, null);
    }
```

UserHelper class is called:

```
@Service
public class UserHelper {
    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;


    public User createUser(...) throws NullParameterException {
        User newUser = new User(username, ...);

        userDAO.save(newUser);

        return newUser;
    }
```

UserDAO's `save()` method subsequently calls `save()` on `UserRepository`:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    public User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

The only place with `@Transactional` is the test method. It needs to be there, because in a separate test method I am lazy loading a many-to-many relation and that needs to happen inside one transaction.

Can you see anything wrong with this code?

EDIT: Error stacktrace

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly

    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:526)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionContext.endTransaction(TransactionContext.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:224)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:313)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:94)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:74)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
    ... 29 more

2016-03-26 20:53:52.913  INFO 2448 --- [       Thread-3] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@20deea7f: startup date [Sat Mar 26 20:53:44 CET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-03-26 20:53:52.924  INFO 2448 --- [       Thread-3] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

Comment: Which exception (class) is being thrown out of the test method exactly? Also, have you tried removing the `@Rollback(false)` annotation, does the exception change then?

Comment: The Rollback is there so that the database changes done in Test environment are actually committed. When it's not there the test case succeeds. I have added the whole stacktrace to the question.

Comment: it looks like the exceptions are not being translated by Spring (there is an aspects for that). Can you add your aspects configuration, whether you're using AspectJ CTW or Spring Aop LTW?

Comment: Rollback false was suggested to me in another SO question to prevent auto-rollback during testing (because I want to inspect the data).

Comment: @StefanoCazzola I am unsure what an aspect configuration is. I have not set up any, I am using Spring Boot and the only config I have done is setting up the datasource in `application.properties`

Comment: @MartinMelka Transaction management in Spring happens through aspects contained in the `spring-aspects` artifact (not in `spring-tx` where you can find only annotations and support classes). These aspects can be woven at runtime / load-time (adding the AOP support to the Spring context) or at compile time (configuring the `aspectj-maven-plugin` in the POM). I never used Spring boot, so I can't tell where it weaves aspects. From th stack trace, it seems that `org.springframework.orm.jpa.aspectj.JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect` is not woven

Comment: @MartinMelka just check your `@Configuration` classes and your POM to understand which weaving method you're using.

Comment: If you have transaction management set up through Spring's `@EnableTransactionManagement` you may specify attributes for that annotation. We need to know the attribute value for `EnableTransactionManagement.mode` or whether you're using the default value of `AdviceMode.PROXY`.

Comment: According to the `spring-boot-dependencies-1.3.3.RELEASE.pom` I am using AspectJ. The only setting I have in the app is `@SpringBootApplication` - the main class is annotated by this.